# When model delete its foreign key in another model become null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

Association is 
Occupation `has_many :users`
User `belongs_to :occupation`

I want when occupation deleted its foreign key in user become null.
How I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `has_many :users, dependent: :nullify`

Comment: Read this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: And this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference